# Скрипт PHP для проверки и удаления других процессов php

Tags: php, linux, процесс

Всем привет, создал скрипт, который удаляет процессы PHP которые работают больше n часов. Я думаю, что это плохой код и хочу почитать ваше мнение для улучшения данного кода, например, где можно использовать более логичные команды.
Данный скрипт я буду добавлять в Crontab. Мне кажется, что его удалят и он не будет работать.

Как мне сделать так, чтобы он самого себя игнорировал?

```
<?php
    if(!isset($argc) || $argc != 2 || !is_numeric($argv[1])){
        echo "Ошибка. Синтакс : \e[32mphp processKill.php [valoarea in secunde]\e[39m." . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }elseif (isset($argc) && $argc === 2){
        $filename = __DIR__ . "/ResultProcessKill/" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".txt";

        $process = shell_exec("ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd | grep php");

        $arrayProcess = explode(PHP_EOL, $process);
        $arrayProcessPart = [];

        $curentDate  = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

        $month  = ["Jan" => 1,"Feb" => 2,"Mar" => 3,"Apr" => 4,"May" => 5, "Jun" => 6, "Aug" => 7, "Aug" => 8, "Sep" => 9, "Oct" => 10, "Nov" => 11, "Dec" => 12];
        $deleteTime = $argv[1];

        for($i = 0; $i < count($arrayProcess) - 1; $i++){
            $arrayProcess[$i] = trim($arrayProcess[$i]);
            $arrayProcessPart[$i] = preg_split(" /[\s,]+/", $arrayProcess[$i]);

            $processDate[$i] = $arrayProcessPart[$i][5] . "-" . $month[$arrayProcessPart[$i][2]] . "-" . $arrayProcessPart[$i][3] . " " . $arrayProcessPart[$i][4];
    
            $diffDate = strtotime($curentDate) - strtotime($processDate[$i]);

            if($diffDate < $deleteTime){
                $deleteTextProcess = "kill " . $arrayProcessPart[$i][0];
                shell_exec($deleteTextProcess);
                $result = "\e[31m";
                $addTex = "Удалён - ";
            }else{
                $result = "\e[39m";
                $addTex = "";
            }
            //$text = "Скрипт работает : " . $diffDate . " сек." . PHP_EOL . $arrayProcess[$i] . PHP_EOL;
            $text = $result . $arrayProcess[$i] . PHP_EOL;
            echo $text;
    
            file_put_contents($filename, $addTex . $text, FILE_APPEND);
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: [Как задать вопрос на инспекцию кода](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1761/209304)

Comment: Функция getmypid() возвращает собственный pid процесса, вот его и игнорируйте. Но не ясно зачем ему самого себя игнорировать. Он же постоянно не запущен, значит под удаление никак попасть не может

Comment: @Mike ой, точно, тупанул. Он же будет выполнятся один раз и завроится. А по коду если предложения для улучшения?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> А по коду если предложения для улучшения?)

Ну Вы сами напросились... :)

```php
    if( !isset($argv) || !is_array($argv) || count( $argv ) < 1 || !is_numeric($argv[1]) || intval($argv[1]) < 1 ) {
        echo "Ошибка. Синтакс : \e[32mphp processKill.php [кол-во секунд]\e[39m." . PHP_EOL;
        exit;
    }
    $deleteTime = intval($argv[1]);
    $process = shell_exec("ps -eo pid,lstart,cmd | grep php");
    $arrayProcess = explode(PHP_EOL, $process);
    if ( is_array( $arrayProcess ) && count( $arrayProcess ) > 0 ) {

       foreach( $arrayProcess as $ap ) {
           $ap = trim($ap);
           $apPart = preg_split(" /[\s,]+/", $ap);
           if ( is_array( $apPart ) && count( $apPart ) >= 6 ) {
               $diffDate = time() - strtotime( $apPart[5]."-".$apPart[2]]."-".$apPart[3]." " .$apPart[4] );
               $result = "\e[39m";
               $addTex = "";
               if( $diffDate < $deleteTime ){
                   shell_exec( "kill " . $apPart[0] );
                   $result = "\e[31m";
                   $addTex = "Удалён - ";
               }
               $text = $result . $ap . PHP_EOL;
               echo $text;
               file_put_contents( __DIR__ . "/ResultProcessKill/" . date("Y-m-d_H-i-s") . ".txt", $addTex . $text, FILE_APPEND);
               
           }
       }

    }
```